# Looping through List Backwards Deleting Items

Tags: c#, list, generics, listitem, enumerate

I have a method which is suppose to loop through a generic list backwards and delete unwanted items based on a condition - after the first item is deleted the program throws the exception

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.'

```
  for (int i = imageFiles.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (imageFiles[i].ImageFileName.Contains("-processed"))
            {
                imageFiles.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
        // delete images from import folder that have "-processed" in filename
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure? This error usually occurs if you are using `foreach`. I tested your code and it isn't throwing an exception. Some different code must be running.

Comment: Perhaps this entire loop is inside a foreach loop (though I can't imagine why you would want that...) anyway, you have the same effect with a single code line using linq: `imageFiles = imageFiles.Where(i => !i.Contains("-processed")).ToList();`

Comment: @ZoharPeled thank you I was looking into linq as an alternative